# Create multiple columns from a data frame using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file, showing below:

[image]

I am trying to create column for each title and also trying to create columns for each type of genre_and_votes so that the output is something like below :
[image]

My code is given below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\mysite\\Desktop\\practice\\book1.csv")
#print(df)
 print(df['Title'].values,df['genre_and_votes'].values)
```

Now for the code above, it creates a df but not be able to create coulmns for each genre and votes, I am not sure how to do this now, need help.

Comment: please provide your data as **text**

Comment: @mozway. I setup a MRE if you want.

Comment: @mozway I have provide data in the code snipet

Comment: @Corralien thanks! I provided another solution, I hope you'll like it ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks for your code. Actually I am new in coding so I feel regex is a  somehow complicated for an amateur like me, is there any easy way to resolve it?

Comment: @RoboBot it is not complicated, eventually advanced. This regex check for strings that do not have commas `[^,]+` followed by space and numbers `\d+`. `extractall` makes one line per match.

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split` and `str.rsplit` before `pivot` your dataframe and merge new columns with your original dataframe:

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['Inner Circle', 'A Time to Embrace'],
                   'genre_and_votes': ['Young adult 161, Mystery 45, Romance 32',
                                       'Christian Fiction 114, Romance 16']})
print(df)


# Output
               title                          genre_and_votes
0       Inner Circle  Young adult 161, Mystery 45, Romance 32
1  A Time to Embrace        Christian Fiction 114, Romance 16
```

Code:

```
out = df['genre_and_votes'].str.split(',').explode() \
                           .str.rsplit(' ', 1, expand=True) \
                           .pivot(columns=0, values=1)

df = pd.concat([df.drop(columns='genre_and_votes'), out], axis=1)
```

Final output

```
>>> df
               title  Mystery  Romance Christian Fiction Young adult
0       Inner Circle       45       32               NaN         161
1  A Time to Embrace      NaN       16               114         NaN
```

Comment: nice and thanks again for providing the df +1

Comment: @Corralien, I am getting an error here mentioned below:
  File "G:\conda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/python/Desktop/book1.py", line 13, in <module>
    out = df['genre_and_votes'].str.split(',').explode() \

  File "G:\conda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3614, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: Do you use a version of `Pandas < 0.25.0`??? You have to update with `conda update pandas`.

Comment: @Corralien: its 0.22.0

Comment: It could be hard to get help with an older version and you will be limited without new features of Pandas. Pandas before version 1.0.0 are subject to many changes without keep compatibility with older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `extractall`, a regex with named capturing groups, and `pivot`:

```
(df.join(df['genre_and_votes'].str.extractall('(?P<genre>[^,]+) (?P<value>\d+)').droplevel('match'))
   .pivot(index='title', columns='genre', values='value')
)
```

output:

```
genre              Mystery  Romance Christian Fiction Young adult
title                                                            
A Time to Embrace      NaN       16               114         NaN
Inner Circle            45       32               NaN         161
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "pivot" function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html